# How to use Google's app password in Ubuntu 17.10 online accounts

Tags: 17.10, online-accounts

I want to authenticate my Ubuntu 17.10 installation with my Google account, using app password. My research shows that this previously worked. However, after generating a fresh app password, when I insert it in Ubuntu Settings -> Online Accounts -> Google, I get the following error:

> Try again with your Google Account password

So is it possible to use app password with Ubuntu 17.10?

Comment: this is still an issue, i'm on 18.04 and it's still not working

Comment: 23.04 and it still doesn't work